# Import only image files into Lightroom library

Tags: lightroom

In Lightroom, in Library, when I select "Import...", and then choose whole folder, is there some setting to automatically add only photo files? I sometimes have photo and video files mixed up in single folder, that was just copied from a camera.

Is there a hidden (in a sense, that I cannot find it) setting, so that I would not have to look for accidental videos, because I don't want to import them to Lightroom?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! It turns out that there *is* a hidden option: hold the alt (option) key, and the "Check All" and "Uncheck All" buttons turn into "Check Videos" and "Uncheck Videos", respectively. From there, you can easily choose to import only photos or only videos, depending on what you need to do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an automatic way.
I do it in this way:

- press 'check all'
- sort by 'media type'
- select all video files ( select first one + press shift + select last one )
- remove flag on one video file ( this uncheck all video files selected)
- press import.